# Using Ubuntu as a main OS on my Netbook Designed for Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, windows-7, ubuntu-netbook

**Hello!**
I have Ubuntu on a virtual box. However, it's way too slow to do anything spectacular. I have this old Netbook that's designed for windows 7. Seen as how it doesn't have a CD slot to install Ubuntu on, I was thinking of putting the Ubuntu iso on a usb and installing it that way. I'd like to use Ubuntu to automate a ton of stuff that I do a lot. I'd also like to improve my security on my network, etc.. So, I have a few questions that I think are good to ask all on one question, instead of people having to search a lot for the answers they're looking for. (including myself)

**Questions:**

- Would the netbook (designed for win7) be able to handle Ubuntu?
- Which Ubuntu OS *should* I use for a crappy netbook laptop? Which one would best suite a small HDD and 2GB~ of RAM?
- My netbook can barely handle win7, seen as it only has 2GB of RAM and a small HDD
- 2GB of ram isn't much, but will it work for Ubuntu as using it as a main OS?
- I have a desktop computer, how hard would all of this to be set up? I assume it'd be time consuming, but pretty basic to do.
- I have a virtualbox for Ubuntu right now, but its really slow. I allocated about 2.5ish GB of RAM, what's the recommended specs for the Ubuntu OS I should install?
- If I've missed anything, I'll add it to the list later. Thank you if you give me a reply. It is appreciated!

***TL;DR what Ubuntu/Linux OS should I install on a crappy netbook for best performance***

***~ Kayden 'iRaaptor' von Raaptor***

EDIT: Netbook is an **Acer Aspire One**

Comment: We can not give you any hardware recommendation, as the performance experience is highly subjective and depends much on applications you use. I can only say that until a few months ago we had stock Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit running stable (though not really fast of course) on an Atom single core Samsung NC10 2GB RAM.

Comment: Sorry about the possibility of this being a duplicate question? I've decided to go with Lubuntu

Comment: Lubuntu certainly is a good choice of a lightweight desktop if you don't need much of other applications that come with stock Ubuntu. Nevertheless personally I did not experience that much of a performance boost as compared to any other flavour.

Comment: I'm gonna go with lubuntu, for the time being. However I might switch to ubuntu if I get annoyed with how simple lubuntu is..

Answer (score 0):

Going with lubuntu. It's quick and easy, and faster than the heavier Ubuntu.